# GraphQL query returns undefined but works fine when I refresh the page?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I am executing a GraphQL query which is fairly complex. Sometimes it returns undefined, but when I refresh the page it works.

I'm building a web application using ReactJS for the frontend, and GraphQL to fetch the data. The query is quite complicated and even when I comment out the entire code in the page (so no information is actually rendered to the page, just they query is executed) , it still sometimes returns undefined.

I've tried the Query in the GraphQL playground and it works fine.

If I look at my server response, the 0.chunk.js.map response time is very long.

Does anyone know what this is likely to be?

The page I am rendering executed 5 different graphQL queries at different levels in the component hierarchy. But it is always the queries in the highest level component that frequently returns undefined.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the response is coming from API? Please do check the network response .

Comment: You don't have to provide the query itself, but some more context would be helpful. For example, including the code where you call and try to use the query result would be good. Is this a web app or are you calling the server from a mobile client or another server? What relevant libraries/frameworks are you using? Are you actually getting a response from the server, but can't access it inside your code?

Comment: I've added more information, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

`data` may be undefined while the query is being fetched from the server. You can provide a default value for it so that the destructuring will work regardless:

```
({ data: { movie } = {}, error, loading }) => {
```

You can even access more nested fields using destructuring, but you need to provide a default value at each level. For example:

```
({ data: { movie: { title } = {} } = {}, error, loading }) => {
```

Note that `data` could end up `null` (as opposed to `undefined`) if the request returns an error and it bubbles all the way up to the root. In this case, defaults won't help. But you can still guard against nulls this way:

```
const movie = data && data.movie
```

or use something like `lodash`'s `get`.

Comment: If nested fields return undefined and I try to access them it such as accessing firstName in data.movie.owner.firstName, how can I put checks to make sure an error doesn't occur. Would I do const firstName = data && data.movie && data.movie.owner & data.movie.owner.firstName. This seems like lot of effort to do every time I try and access a nested field!

Comment: Yup. If you've already got some logic like `if (error) return ...` then that's not really necessary. You can move the destructuring from the function signature to below that check. That way, if data is null due to errors, the destructuring code will never be reached.